# How can i have both MatrixBase and DenseBase in a template function in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have found out that i can create a templated eigen function like this:

```
template <>
CIL_EXPORTS
    void gpa<std::complex<float>>(const Eigen::EigenBase<std::complex<float>>& Data);
```

In the function i also need methods from the DenseBase. How would i get access to methods from both base classes?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which functions do you want? What do you mean by base classes - is `gpa` a member function? If it is, does the class inherit from both EigenBase and DenseBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "Eigen::EigenBase < std::complex < float > > " does not make sense. EigenBase template argument is the derived class, not the scalar type. It must be a Matrix, Array, etc. In general it should be a template parameter. Please, read this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) first.

Anyway, once you get a correct EigenBase or DenseBase, you can access to the derived class members (not the base class!) with arg.derived() or by casting it to the derived type once: const Derived& mat(arg.derived());

Comment: Okay, thanks. Missed out a few things when learned about Eigen